# UIWebView didn't load!

Tags: iphone, ipad

I used UIWebView to load a local html file to get content of it. But it seems not work. So what was the reason?

```
CGRect tempRect= CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 480);
    myWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:tempRect];
    myWebView.delegate=self;[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathFileHttp]]];
```

Comment: ann errors? what is pathFileHttp?

Comment: Sr about the name. It is not right. pathFileHttp is path to html local file. It's exists.

Answer (score 0):

I would double-check that pathFileHttp is actually accessible to your app.

Also, have you added myWebView to whatever parentview you're using?  Is it the front-most subview?